# INotifyDataErrorInfo validation not working although GetErrors method called in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a ValidatableObject class implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Interesting thing is when I create new instance my ValidatableModel in viewmodel and call Validate method after view loaded it works. But when I created My model in constructor of viewmodel and call Validate method after view loaded it doesn't works.

What is the difference between create instance before view loaded and after view loaded. Here is some code, i simplified a bit

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private MyModel _myModel;
        public MyModel MyModel
        {
            get { return _myModel; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _myModel, value);
            }
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            MyModel = new MyModel();
        }

        //this not working, I calls this after view loaded 
        public void Validate()
        {
            MyModel.Validate();
        }

        //this  working,  I calls this after view loaded 
        public void Validate()
        {
            MyModel = new MyModel();
            MyModel.Validate();
        }
    }

   [JsonObject]
    public partial class MyModel : ValidatableObject
    {
        private string _id;
        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
        }

        private string _status;
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Field is mandatory")]
        public string status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _status, value); }
        }

        private string _requestId;
        public string requestId
        {
            get { return _requestId; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _requestId, value); }
        }
    }


                                <TextBox Width="135"
                                         Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}"
                                         Text="{Binding MyModel.status,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: What happens if you add null checking on your Validate method? Would it still fire? like, MyModel?.Validate();

Comment: @Mac I don't understand. what will I check, MyModel not null, there is no exception or output error.

Comment: Yeah inside your Validate method add null check for MyModel, like if(MyModel != null) MyModel.Validate(); I'm saying this because we too experience that problem I think it has something todo with navigationCache but I'm not that certain but if we add null checks the issue is solved I need to find some more explanation though.

Comment: @Mac I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: I removed everything on my view. only textbox remained. and validation works.I don't know why other user controls are causing the problem

Comment: I see, are those custom user controls?

Comment: Yes, I have many custom user controls